# Android : How to change accessibility reading order

Tags: accessibility, talkback

I wonder how to change **accessibility (talk back)** reading order when using swipe left / right gesture to next item / previous item. The nextFocusForward / nextFocusDown methods are used but not work at all.
Thank You.

Comment: You should ask on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -2):

Adding tabindex="0" for html element will get the focus based on its order in the Dom, and we need to add role of the element will read its type as shown in below example

```
<a href="ex.png" tabindex="0" role="button"> read as button</a>
```

to get the focus you have options using jquery methods focusIn(),focusOut().focus().

to get the focus based on some event as below :

```
$("#elementId").first().focus();// it will get the focus based on event
```